# Split string at first space and get 2 sub strings in c#

Tags: c#

I have a string like this

```
INIXA4 Agartala
INAGX4 Agatti Island
```

I want to split such a way that it will be like `INAGX4` & `Agatti Island`

If I am using  `var commands = line.Split(' ');`

It splits like `INAGX4, Agatti, Island`

If there is 4 space it give 4 array of data.How can I achieve only 2 substring

Comment: use input.Split

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since you have `2` space, `Split(' ')` generates an array with 3 elements.

Based on your example, you can get the index of your first white space and generate your strings with [`Substring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring) based on that index.

```
var s = "INAGX4 Agatti Island";
var firstSpaceIndex = s.IndexOf(" ");
var firstString = s.Substring(0, firstSpaceIndex); // INAGX4
var secondString = s.Substring(firstSpaceIndex + 1); // Agatti Island
```

Comment: completely wrong, use wrong, use input.Split

Answer (score 45):

You can just use

[string.Split(char separator, int count, StringSplitOptions options = System.StringSplitOptions.None)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_String_Split_System_Char_System_Int32_System_StringSplitOptions_)

overload of `string` object and pass `2` as count where it is `"The maximum number of substrings to return."`
Here is an example:

```
var input = "INAGX4 Agatti Island";
var splitted = input.Split(' ', 2);
Console.WriteLine(splitted[0]); // INAGX4
Console.WriteLine(splitted[1]); // Agatti Island
```

Comment: Wrong but still useful! `' '` is of type `char`, not of type `char[]`. But as qqqqqqq wrote, `new[] { ' ' }` will do the job.

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this, using the `IndexOf` and `Substring` methods of `string`:

```
var str = "INAGX4 Agatti Island";
var indexOfFirstSpace = str.IndexOf(" ");
var first = str.Substring(0, indexOfFirstSpace);
var second = str.Substring(indexOfFirstSpace+1);
```

For a detailed documentation about the above methods, please have a look at the following links:

- [IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string str = "INAGX4 Agatti Island";
string firstStinrg = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(' '));
string secondsStrig = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(' ')+1);
```

Comment: wrong, use input.Split